# populate entry field within a class using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm tying to insert a default value that will be edited into an entry box using tkinter. The below solution works when I remove it from a class, but doesn't work within a class. My ultimate goal is to dynamically update this value based on a result from sql, but first I need to get the default value to show. That's where I'm running into trouble at the moment. Any insight into what I'm missing is greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        v = IntVar()
        self.JobNumber = Entry(self, width = 45, text = v  ) # Job Number 
        self.JobNumber.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, sticky = W)
        v.set(100)

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Did you tried `textvariable` parameter instead of `text`?](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: I did, but I get the same result. It doesn't populate. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Your `v` is local variable, make it `self.v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `ttk`, and `ttk` is very sensitive to local variables. In this case, `v` is local and is getting garbage collected.

There's no need to use `textvariable`. You can set the value of the `Entry` widget using its insert method:

```
self.JobNumber.insert(0, "this is the default value")
```

If you really feel you need to use `textvariable`, make sure it's not a local variable. For example:

```
self.v = IntVar()
...
self.v.set(100)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Both of these changes worked like a charm. Thank you. I spent a full day beating my head against this one.